# Pyperclip install error on Centos 7 with python 3.6.3

Tags: centos, python

I'm trying to install Pyperclip on a vm - Centos 7:

## pip install pyperclip

Collecting pyperclip
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyperclip/: There was a **problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]** certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777) - skipping
  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyperclip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyperclip**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error with the following command:

#curl -k https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python

After this I ran the following command to install pyperclip

#pip install pyperclip